# Crosspost Discord Message using Discord4j

Tags: kotlin, discord4j

I have a DiscordBot which was written with Discord4j using Kotlin.
I send EmbedMessages with it and I want to publish these messages automatically. Does anyone have a clue how to do this? I have an embedbuilder and send the message with the following function.

```
fun sendEmbedMessage(gateway: GatewayDiscordClient, embed: EmbedCreateSpec, channelId: String) {
    gateway.getChannelById(Snowflake.of(channelId))
        .ofType(GuildMessageChannel::class.java)
        .flatMap { channel -> channel.createMessage(embed) }
        .subscribe()
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [publish](https://javadoc.io/static/com.discord4j/discord4j-core/3.2.2/discord4j/core/object/entity/Message.html#publish()):

```kotlin
fun sendEmbedMessage(gateway: GatewayDiscordClient, embed: EmbedCreateSpec, channelId: String) {
    gateway.getChannelById(Snowflake.of(channelId))
        .ofType(GuildMessageChannel::class.java)
        .flatMap { channel -> channel.createMessage(embed) }
        .flatMap { message -> message.publish() }
        .subscribe()
}
```